# Apache server starts automatically after stopping the service

Tags: centos, apache-httpd

What can cause httpd to start automatically after stopping it?

In a bash script I need to first stop apache web server. This is the script:

```
apachectl stop;
while pgrep httpd; do sleep 1; done
echo "[Apache server stopped]"
```

When I run the script it prints running apache processes until there isn't any running process and prints *[Apache server stopped]*

Then running the command `pgrep httpd` prints nothing, but if I enter a website hosted by the server, then `pgrep httpd` prints some httpd processes.

Is this the right way to stop apache? Why does it start automatically after running `apachectl stop`? If it is related to *KeepAliveTime*, how do I force the running child processes to stop?

Edit: This is also true for running `service httpd stop` or `apachectl stop` commands in command line.

Comment: You probably have a service monitor running that only sees the service exiting and tries to resume operations.

Comment: just to double-check something: check for the presence of `/usr/bin/systemctl`, please. if this is a systemd system I know exactly what's going on.

Comment: inetd service ?

Comment: @strugee `/usr/bin/systemctl` doesn't exists.

Comment: @Kiwy inetd is not in the `service [TAB]` list

Comment: what linux distribution do you use?

Answer (score 2):

[`upstart`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/), the service manager, can restart httpd if it is set to [`respawn`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/wiki/Stanzas#respawn).

`apachectl stop` stop's the process without notifying `upstart`

Try:

```
service httpd stop
```

By the way, when you issue any of the `stop` like commands to apache it will stop accepting new connections. The `gracefuls` will additionally allow it to complete any currently open connections.

Comment: OP has "CentOS" tagged, but I agree that something similar is probably what's going on. They may have some sort of service monitor running.

Comment: What do you mean about the centos tag?

Comment: @mtm Thanks, but as JoelDavis mentioned, I use CentOS not Ubuntu

Comment: @Omid Centos6? `init --help | tail -1`

Comment: Yes. Centos6. `init --help` shows that it uses `upstart`! but `stop httpd` returns this error: `stop: Unknown job: httpd`

Comment: If `httpd` is still using a sysvinit script then it won't have the respawn config, unless that's a default for upstart running sysvinit stuff.  I tried adding `httpd` on a centos vm and am not getting the same kill/restart behavior : /

Comment: 'service httpd stop' doesn't work?

Comment: @Jeight No!....

Answer (score 2):

#### Confirming a service

On CentOS 6 I would investigate if the `httpd` service is accessible.

```
$ service --status-all |& grep httpd
httpd is stopped
```

You can disable this service using `chkconfig`:

```
$ chkconfig --list | grep httpd
httpd           0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off

$ sudo chkconfig httpd off

$ chkconfig --list | grep httpd
httpd           0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
```

#### But it keeps starting when I access it?

Since you're dealing with CentOS 6 you're likely using Upstart. You can see if `httpd` the service is under its control.

```
$ initctl list
```

You'll see it in the list, I do not have this configuration to show. I would assume based on your description of the issue that your system has `httpd` set like this:

```
httpd stop/waiting
```

Which, as I understand it, means that if Upstart sees that service being accessed, it will start it back up. Upstart will maintain a service script for `httpd` under `/etc/init` if this is the case. You'll want to go inside that file and disable the service and reload the config. It likely has a `respawn` section which is causing this:

#### Example

```
$ more /etc/init/prefdm.conf 
# prefdm - preferred display manager
#
# Starts gdm/xdm/etc by preference

start on stopped rc RUNLEVEL=5

stop on starting rc RUNLEVEL=[!5]

console output
respawn
respawn limit 10 120
exec /etc/X11/prefdm -nodaemon
```

#### References

- [How to write CentOS initialization scripts with Upstart](http://www.openlogic.com/wazi/bid/281586/How-to-write-CentOS-initialization-scripts-with-Upstart)

Answer (score 0):

Look for it in `/etc/inittab`, could be that someone put it to respawn.

Comment: content of the file is: `id:3:initdefault:`

Comment: Hence that is not the problem.